# Error integrating NCRport 2.10.0 with Qt 5.1.0

Tags: qt, reporting-services, report, qt5, qmake

i start integerating NCReport to my application , but alway i got these errors

her is my .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-08-14T17:44:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------


QT       += core gui sql xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4){
QT += widgets printsupport
DEFINES += HAVE_QT5
}



TARGET = gestionstock6
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    produit.cpp \
    customqtablewidget.cpp \
    customdelegatecombobox.cpp \
    customproxy.cpp \
    client.cpp \
    bondelivraison.cpp \
    chercherproduit.cpp \
    chercherclientproduitwidget.cpp \
    fournisseur.cpp \
    chercherfournisseur.cpp \
    vente.cpp

    HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    customqtablewidget.h \
    customdelegatecombobox.h \
    customproxy.h \
    client.h \
    bondelivraison.h \
    chercherproduit.h \
    produit.h  \
    produit.h \
    produit.h \
    chercherclientproduitwidget.h \
    fournisseur.h \
    chercherfournisseur.h \
    vente.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    produit.ui \
    client.ui \
    bondelivraison.ui \
    chercherproduit.ui \
    chercherclientproduitwidget.ui \
    fournisseur.ui \
    chercherfournisseur.ui \
    vente.ui


       INCLUDEPATH = "E:\apprendreQt\gestionstock6\includes\include"

       LIBS = "E:\apprendreQt\gestionstock6\includes\lib\NCReport2.lib"
```

and this is my implementation of ncreport

```
void Vente::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    NCReport *report = new NCReport(this);
    report->reset(true);
    report->setReportFile("E:\apprendreQt\build-gestionstock6-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\reports\abdeu.xml");

    report->runReportToQtPreview();
}
```

when i compile my project files , i got errors below

i have tried many times but same problem

```
E:\apprendreQt\gestionstock6\vente.cpp:222: erreur : undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8NCReport5resetEb'

E:\apprendreQt\gestionstock6\vente.cpp:223: erreur : undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8NCReport13setReportFileERK7QString'

E:\apprendreQt\gestionstock6\vente.cpp:225: erreur : undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8NCReport20runReportToQtPreviewEv'

collect2.exe:-1: erreur : error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using incompatible libraries.

This tells me that you're using the MinGW compiler

```
report->setReportFile("E:\apprendreQt\build-gestionstock6-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\reports\abdeu.xml");
```

but in your `.pro` file, you're including a static linking library from a different compiler (most likely MS Visual Studio)

```
LIBS = "E:\apprendreQt\gestionstock6\includes\lib\NCReport2.lib"
```

libraries for MinGW should have a `.a` extension, not a `.lib` one.

Not only that, you're using the LIBS variable incorrectly. For a MinGW compiler, you should specify the library path(with `-L`) and the library itself(with `-l`) separately.

You could do this on separate lines:

```
LIBS += "-L/path/to/libraries"
LIBS += "-lmylibrary.a"
```

or in a single line:

```
LIBS += "-L/path/to/libraries -lmylibrary.a"
```

Comment: i have used LIBS += "-LE:\apprendreQt\gestionstock6\includes\lib -llibNCReport2.a" but i got same errors

Comment: Does `libNCReport2.a` exist? Are you using a version of the NCReport library compiled for Qt5 or Qt4?

Comment: i'm using this "2.10.0.MinGW.Qt4.8.5.eval" i get only this because into to official site there is no .a lib for qt5

Comment: If they only offer a `.lib` linking library then that's your problem. MSVC libraries are not compatible with the MinGW linker. You'll have to create your own linking library from the `.dll` or you'll have to compile your own code with the MS compiler.

Comment: is there any esay solution to print report with NCreport ?